# Increment a Varchar in SQL keeping the number of digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
//@RunningNo is in varchar(6) format

SET @RunningNo = SUBSTRING(@CaseNo,12,6)

SELECT @RunningNo AS runningNo1 //OUTPUT: 00099

SET @RunningNo = @RunningNo + 1

SELECT @RunningNo AS runningNo2 //OUTPUT: 100
```

Can I keep the number of digits so that the second output will be `000100` instead of `100`?

Comment: Use `format()` if you want to format a number to a particular string format.

Comment: Coding 101: Use the correct datatype for the purpose, only convert to a string when required to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution here is probably to declare `@RunningNo` as an integer, then use `FORMAT` when you want to view that running total in a certain format:

```
DECLARE @RunningNo INT = 99;
SET @RunningNo = @RunningNo + 1
SELECT FORMAT(@RunningNo, 'D6')
```